# React Typescript: Cannot assign component to element

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I need to map my JSX component(FC) inside an object for dynamic rendering.
This is what I have come up with so far:

> Interface for Object

```js
interface Mappings {
  EC2: {
    component: React.FC<{}>;
    name: string;
    description: string;
  };
}

export enum ResourcesEnum {
  EC2 = 'EC2',
  S3 = 'S3',
}
```

> The mapping object defined in the same file:

[image]

> **Error** message:

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature 
'(props: { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
```

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: `<EC2 />` is of type `JSX.Element`, so you could modify your `Mappings` interface with the correct type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `React.FC<{}>` describes *the component itself* rather than an instance of the component.  `Mappings` is expecting that your object contains `component: EC2` instead of `component: <EC2 />`.

You either need to change your values to match your types or change your types to match your values.  Either way is fine.  If you want to keep `component: <EC2 />` then your type needs to be `component: JSX.Element`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the type of the component to `JSX.Element` or `Element` since `<EC2 />` is `JSX`

```
interface Mappings {
  EC2: {
    component: JSX.Element;
    name: string;
    description: string;
  };
}
```